# three integers compare

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have three integers

I would like to determine what is the highest and which is the lowest value using Objective-C

Thank you!

Comment: keep it simple, just compare.

Comment: I would, but the loop shown below is much simpler than inventing my own algorithm I think

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is good to store that numbers in an array. Just plain C array is good enough and in Objective-C best for performance. To find a minimum you can use this function. Similar for maximum.

```
int find_min(int numbers[], int N){
    int min = numbers[0];
    for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
        if(min>numbers[i])min=numbers[i];

    return min;
}
```

If that is just three numbers you can do the comparisons manually for best performance. There is a MIN() and MAX() macro in Cocoa in Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h. For the maximum, just do:

```
int m = MAX(myI1, MAX(myI2, myI3));
```

This may be scaled to more numbers and may be faster than the first approach using loop.

Comment: MIN() and MAX() are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no short and elegant neither a generalized way for that in Cocoa.

Plain C Array + custom loop would be the best. With an NSArray you would have to wrap the Integers in NSNumbers without getting any benefit out of that.

Comment: thank you. a plain c array and a custom loop indeed work just fine.

Comment: Not true; array can valueForKeyPath of max and min. No need to manually iterate.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C's built in `MAX(a,b)` and `MIN(a,b)` macros only work for two values.

I have two macros I've created for using 2 or more values called multi-max and multi-min (MMAX and MMIN)

Here is their definition, just copy paste into your .h

```
#define MMAX(...) ({\
long double __inputs[(sizeof((long double[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(long double))] = {__VA_ARGS__};\
long double __maxValue = __inputs[0];\
for (int __i = 0; __i < (sizeof((long double[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(long double)); ++__i) {\
long double __inputValue = __inputs[__i];\
__maxValue = __maxValue>__inputValue?__maxValue:__inputValue;\
}\
__maxValue;\
})

#define MMIN(...) ({\
long double __inputs[(sizeof((long double[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(long double))] = {__VA_ARGS__};\
long double __minValue = __inputs[0];\
for (int __i = 0; __i < (sizeof((long double[]){__VA_ARGS__})/sizeof(long double)); ++__i) {\
long double __inputValue = __inputs[__i];\
__minValue = __minValue<__inputValue?__minValue:__inputValue;\
}\
__minValue;\
})
```

Example use:

```
x = MMAX(2,3,9,5);
//sets x to 9.
```